# Is there any way to play these videos in Linux?

Tags: linux, video, moonlight

I haven't been able to play [videos from here](http://myvideos.stanford.edu/player/slplayer.aspx?coll=ea60314a-53b3-4be2-8552-dcf190ca0c0b&co=40ac3a89-a6a2-439f-8f74-64d250a12818&o=true). I tried Moonlight, but it doesn't show an image, just sound, and *sometimes* some part of the image, but mostly a black canvass. Thanks.

Comment: Works here (chromium 15.0.something, x86_64).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can extract the url from the HTML-source and use mplayer:

```
$ mplayer -ao pulse mms://proedvid.stanford.edu/videocontent/knuth/musings/981203/981203-knuth-500.wmv
```

The playback (audio/video) works fine on a Ubuntu 11.04 system.

You can automate this a bit, e.g. via:

```
$ curl -s -S 'http://myvideos.stanford.edu/player/slplayer.aspx?coll=ea60314a-53b3-4be2-8552-dcf190ca0c0b&co=40ac3a89-a6a2-439f-8f74-64d250a12818&o=true' | \
  grep mms  | sed 's/.*\(mms:\/\/[^"]\+\)".*/\1/'
mms://proedvid.stanford.edu/videocontent/knuth/musings/981203/981203-knuth-500.wmv
```

Comment: This works (and the videos are great :), Using `ffmpeg -i` it shows 2 video streams (500kbps and 300kbps) and 1 audio.. I demuxed the 500kpbs (358.7 MB) and the audio (49.0 MB). The full file is 568.3 MB, so this means 160.6 MB is *extra*. I haven't been able to demux this phantom stream, but something is going on.. The video is 99.37 minutes and the 500kbps stream's size confirms that pretty closely..  Any ideas about what is going on with this? ... The demux commands were `ffmpeg -map 0:0 -vcodec copy -i "$1" -an -y "$1".0.wmv` and similar for the audio with `.asf` output...

Comment: PS.. I used a different `mplayer` command to your example to get the stream, but the 'mms://...` was the same. Here is the command I used: `mplayer -dumpstream -dumpfile "Donald-Knuth.wmv" "$( curl -s -S "$URI" |grep mms |sed -r 's|.*(mms://[^"]+)".*|\1|' )"`